An identity about derivatives of $C^{2}$ functions.
Suppose $U, V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\varphi:U\to V$ is a $C^{2}$ function and it has a $C^{2}$ inverse $\varphi^{-1}:
 V\to U$. Let $D\varphi(x) = (\varphi^{i}_{x_{j}}(x)), D(\varphi^{-1})(y) = ((\varphi^{-1})^{i}_{y_{j}}(y))$ denote the matrices of the first order derivatives of $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$, respectively. When do some calculating, I found that the following identity might be true for all $i = 1, \dots, n$.
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\left((\varphi^{-1})^{j}_{y_{i}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right)_{x_{j}} = 0.
 \end{align*}
For example, suppose $U = V = (0, \infty)\times (0, \infty)$, $\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2}) = \left(x_{1}x_{2}, \frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)$, then $\varphi^{-1}(y_{1}, y_{2}) = \left(\sqrt{\frac{y_{1}}{y_{2}}}, \sqrt{y_{1}y_{2}}\right)$ and
\begin{align*}
  D\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2}) = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{2} & x_{1} \\
   -\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}^{2}} & \frac{1}{x_{1}}
  \end{bmatrix}, \\
  D(\varphi^{-1})(\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2})) = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{1}{2x_{2}} & \frac{x_{1}^{2}}{2x_{2}} \\
   \frac{1}{2x_{1}} & \frac{x_{1}}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}.
 \end{align*}
Hence $\det(D\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2})) = \frac{2x_{2}}{x_{1}}$ and
\begin{align*}
  & \left((\varphi^{-1})^{1}_{y_{1}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right)_{x_{1}} + \left((\varphi^{-1})^{2}_{y_{1}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right)_{x_{2}} \\
  = & \left(\frac{1}{2x_{2}}\frac{2x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)_{x_{1}} + \left(\frac{1}{2x_{1}}\frac{2x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)_{x_{2}} \\
  = & -\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}} + \frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}} = 0. \\
  & \left((\varphi^{-1})^{1}_{y_{2}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right)_{x_{1}} + \left((\varphi^{-1})^{2}_{y_{2}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right)_{x_{2}} \\
  = & \left(-\frac{x_{1}^{2}}{2x_{2}}\frac{2x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)_{x_{1}} + \left(\frac{x_{1}}{2}\frac{2x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)_{x_{2}} \\
  = & -1 + 1 = 0.
 \end{align*}
So does the identity above be in general true?

I have real trouble understanding your notation. Can you check your sum formula, there seems to be at least a $D$ missing. Furthermore, can you make clear how the summation is taken: the dependence on $j$ of the second factor is not clear. Does the identity you are curious about look like $(D\varphi^{-1}) \varphi$det$(\varphi)$?

This is hard for me to parse, but have you thought about $D(\varphi^{-1})(y) = (D\varphi(x))^{-1}$ with $\varphi(x)=y$, and then $(\det A)A^{-1}  = \text{cof}(A)^\top$?

@Hrodelbert $(\varphi^{-1})^{j}{y{i}}(\varphi(x))$ means the partial derivative with respect to $y_{i}$ of the $j$-th component $(\varphi^{-1})^{j}$ of the inverse $\varphi^{-1}$, taking value at the point $\varphi(x)$, not to multiply a function $\varphi(x)$.

Thanks for the clarification. Then, isn't $\varphi(x_1,x_2) = (x_1, x_2)$ a counter-example?

@Hrodelbert No, it is not a counterexample. Note that there are partial derivatives with respect to $x_{j}$ on each term of the sum in the identity.

Sorry, my bad, I meant to write $\varphi(x_1, x_2) = (x_1^2, x_2^2)/2$. Then $D\varphi = diag(x_1, x_2)$ with Det$(D\varphi) = x_1 x_2$ and differentiating along rows or columns will yield $1$.

@Hrodelbert In this example, the result of the identity is not $1$. In fact, if $i = 1$, $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\left((\varphi^{-1})^{j}{y{1}}(\varphi(x))\det(D\varphi(x))\right){x{j}} = \left(\frac{1}{x_{1}}x_{1}x_{2}\right){x{1}} + \left(0x_{1}x_{2}\right){x{2}} = 0$. When $i = 2$, the result is also $0$. By the way, we need to assume $x_{1} > 0$ and $x_{2} > 0$ to ensure that $\varphi$ has a $C^{2}$ inverse.

I'll use Einstein summation for this,
$$\delta^j_k = \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^k}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \left( (\varphi^{-1})^j(\varphi(x)) \right) = \frac{\partial (\varphi^{-1})^j}{\partial y^\ell}(\varphi(x)) \frac{\partial \varphi^\ell}{\partial x^k}(x)$$
Where we've used the chain rule. The last term is a component of the Jacobian of $\varphi$,
$$\frac{\partial \varphi^\ell}{\partial x^k}(x) = J^\ell_k(x)$$
We can multiply both sides by the matrix inverse of the Jacobian, which I'm going to call $K$ to reduce clutter,
$$\delta^j_k K^k_i(x) = K^j_i(x) = \frac{\partial (\varphi^{-1})^j}{\partial y^\ell}(\varphi(x)) J^\ell_k(x) K^k_i(x) = \frac{\partial (\varphi^{-1})^j}{\partial y^\ell}(\varphi(x)) \delta^\ell_i = \frac{\partial (\varphi^{-1})^j}{\partial y^i}(\varphi(x))$$
Your expression is then,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \left( \frac{\partial (\varphi^{-1})^j}{\partial y^i}(\varphi(x)) |J(x)| \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \left( K^j_i(x) |J(x)| \right)$$
Where $|J(x)|$ is the Jacobian determinant. Now that everything is a function of only $x$, again to reduce clutter I will stop showing the function arguments, they are always $x$.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \left( K^j_i |J| \right) = \frac{\partial K^j_i}{\partial x^j}  |J| + K^j_i \frac{\partial |J|}{\partial x^j}$$
$$= -K^j_k \frac{\partial J^k_\ell}{\partial x^j} K^\ell_i |J| + K^j_i \frac{\partial J^k_\ell}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial |J|}{\partial J^k_\ell}$$
$$= -K^j_k H^k_{j \ell} K^\ell_i |J| + K^j_i H^k_{j \ell} K^\ell_k |J|$$
For the left term we used an identity for the derivative of the inverse of a matrix $\partial_x (M^{-1}) = -M^{-1} (\partial_x M) M^{-1}$. For the right term we used an identity for the derivative of the determinant of an invertible matrix with respect to a component $\partial |M| / \partial M^i_j = (M^{-1})^j_i |M|$, and the chain rule. $H^k_{j \ell} = \partial^2_{j \ell} \varphi^k$ is the Hessian of $\varphi$. In the second term we now swap the summation indices $j$ and $\ell$,
$$= -K^j_k H^k_{j \ell} K^\ell_i |J| + K^\ell_i H^k_{\ell j} K^j_k |J|$$
$$= -K^j_k H^k_{j \ell} K^\ell_i |J| + K^j_k H^k_{j \ell} K^\ell_i |J|$$
$$= 0$$

Nice calculations! I have learned a lot from it, thank you very much.
